# Browserify + Remapify (Gulp workflow)

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I've successfully got Browserify to compile my JavaScript entry files, but I want to utilise the Remapify plugin so as to not have to specify the full relative path upon requiring a module every time.

For example:

```
require('components/tabs.js')
```

Rather than:

```
require('../../components/tabs/tabs.js').
```

But I cannot get the shorter module references to map to the corresponding file... "Error: Cannot find module [specified_ref] from [file]".

Have I misconfigured Remapify, or is there something wrong with my wider Browserify setup? I am new to Broswerify and Gulp having previously used Require.js and Grunt. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information about my setup.

If alternatively you can recommend an alternative Gulp task file that will do all of this, thereby throwing my current task out the window, by all means. I wasn't able to find many Browserify + Remapify examples.

**Directory Structure**

I have my modules (components) in the following directory: './src/components', so for example: './src/components/tabs/tabs.js'.

I am requiring these modules in a JS file for a given page of the app, which are in: './src/pages', so for example, './src/pages/portfolio/portfolio.js'.

**Gulp Browserify Task**

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var config      = require('../config');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var remapify    = require('remapify');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var glob        = require('glob');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  var entries = glob.sync(config.src.pages + '/**/*.js');
  return browserify({
      entries: entries,
      debug: true
    })

    // (Remapify:)
    .plugin(remapify, [{ src: config.src.components + '/**/*.js', expose: 'components', cwd: config.srcDir }])

    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.js))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

**Page.js**

```
'use strict';

var tabs = require('components/tabs.js'); // (Doesn't work, but I want it to)
// var tabs = require('../../components/tabs/tabs.js'); // (Does work)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remapify has all sorts of problems. I suggest giving my [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) plugin a shot.

For your situation usage would look something like:

```js
var pathmod = require('pathmodify');
// ...
.plugin(pathmod(), {mods: [
  pathmod.mod.dir('components', '/path/to/src/components'),
]})
```